# Rust Type cast String as Bytes (without converting)

Tags: string, rust, casting, byte

I have sent a byte stream of signature as string using tokio  `stream.write_all(sign.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();`

In client side I am getting it as string, say:

```
[132, 40, 243, 14, 49, 231, 64, 130, 236, 226, 5, 180, 166, 50, 2, 49, 124, 248, 235, 53, 7, 204, 124, 101, 54, 230, 225, 25, 201, 47, 159, 52]
```

Now to verify the signature with public key, I need to use it as bytes (the crate I am using does not allow to use signature as string)
But the problem is, when I convert the sign to bytes (`as_bytes()`), it converts the string to a byte stream, say:

```
[91, 49, 51, 50, 44, 32, 52, 48, 44, 32, 50, 52, 51, 44, 32, 49, 52, 44, 32, 52, 57, 44, 32, 50, 51, 49, 44, 32, 54, 52, 44, 32, 49, 51, 48, 44, 32, 50, 51, 54, 44, 32, 50, 50, 54, 44, 32, 53, 44, 32, 49, 56, 48, 44, 32, 49, 54, 54, 44, 32, 53, 48, 44, 32, 50, 44, 32, 52, 57, 44, 32, 49, 50, 52, 44, 32, 50, 52, 56, 44, 32, 50, 51, 53, 44, 32, 53, 51, 44, 32, 55, 44, 32, 50, 48, 52, 44, 32, 49, 50, 52, 44, 32, 49, 48, 49, 44, 32, 53, 52, 44, 32, 50, 51, 48, 44, 32, 50, 50, 53, 44, 32, 50, 53, 44, 32, 50, 48, 49, 44, 32, 52, 55, 44, 32, 49, 53, 57, 44, 32, 53, 50, 93]
```

But I want to type cast the exact string as bytes.
So the bytes should be like this too:

```
[132, 40, 243, 14, 49, 231, 64, 130, 236, 226, 5, 180, 166, 50, 2, 49, 124, 248, 235, 53, 7, 204, 124, 101, 54, 230, 225, 25, 201, 47, 159, 52]
```

Any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: I don't think "cast" means what you think it means. For one, "cast" is usually infallible, but what if the string you got says `[42, lolnope {}#`? What bytes should the key have? `str::as_bytes` will give you the actual bytes, e.g. it will give you a `92` as the ascii/utf8 value for `'['`. You'll need to parse your string, i.e. convert the three bytes `"132"` into a single one. Examples: [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b3b89d9393c1d3f9754a734d40fed551) or with `serde_json::from_str::<Vec<u8>>(s)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deserialize the the string into bytes somewhere. Earlier is better, since the bytes take up much less space than the string, but you can decide based on your needs.

You also need to figure out which format your input is. I'm assuming it's JSON for this answer. The following uses [`serde_json`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.95/serde_json/index.html) to deserialize the string into a `Vec<u8>`. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1052dcab8d1575e1350a28aeed08e97c)

```rs
// Replace this with wherever your input comes from.
let input = "[132, 40, 243, 14, 49, 231, 64, 130, 236, 226, 5, 180, 166, 50, 2, 49, 124, 248, 235, 53, 7, 204, 124, 101, 54, 230, 225, 25, 201, 47, 159, 52]";
let bytes: Vec<u8> = serde_json::from_str(input).unwrap();
stream.write_all(&bytes).await.unwrap();
```